# GPO best practice

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Right now I have GPO's linked to OU's  but users are in security groups for policies to work, is it better to keep them in OU's vs security policies? Is there a best practice on this not using security groups?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm gettin what you're trying. How would you link a GPO to a security group exclusively?

Comment: Sorry this was for printer groups only... the rest are tied to users settings. Just want to make sure its the best practice... for adding users to print. Its been a long time since doing this so trying to refresh my knowledge at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you described. You can use the OU structure, security filtering, or WMI filters to fine-tune who applies your GPO settings. I would avoid blocking GPO inheritance on OUs whenever possible.

You can be inclusive or exclusive in applying GPOs with security filtering depending on the use case. For instance you may apply GPOs to all 'Authenticated Users' in an OU (that means users/computers), but use security groups for exclusion only. That way you can easily point to a group to identify who is exempt from that policy. Think security setting overrides.

On the other hand, you may have multiple groups of users/computers sharing the same OU and you want certain settings to apply to one group and not the other. In this situation you may filter the GPO only to members of a security group and remove the 'apply group policy' right from Authenticated Users.

I would recommend having a group naming convention so it is easy to identify which groups are associated with security filtered domain GPOs. Something like "GPO Apply - [GPO Name]" or "GPO Deny - [GPO Name]".

You may also create OUs to apply policies. My preference is to only create OUs when delegating administrative access. Keep your directory structure simple and easy to manage. WMI filters slightly increase GPO processing time and should be used sparingly. For this reason, I only use WMI filters to target major Windows operating system versions for applying security settings unique to that version.